# Magento_2.3.0 Message queue topic "inventory.reservations.updateSalabilityStatus" is not configured

Tags: php, checkout, magento2.3.0

After clicking the place order button I'm getting this error msg. can anyone have solutions?

**Message queue topic "inventory.reservations.updateSalabilityStatus" is not configured.**

Comment: try to run this command and check `bin/magento queue:consumers:list`

Comment: Okay. but still the issue is not fixed. @viru